# What sort of questions are typical when interviewing for an Assistant Professor position in Ireland?

Tags: computer-science, interview, ireland

I have an upcoming interview for an assistant professor position in computing in a university in Ireland. The interviewers are Vice President Academic Affairs and Research, Dean and Vice Dean of the Department of Computing and a HR consultant.

Could academics who are familiar with the Ireland system advise me on the sort of questions that are typically asked in these interviews? Looking at similar questions asked on Academia.SE for UK, I understand that in UK, the questions are typically about funding, REF and TEF (although I believe REF and TEF are not applicable in Ireland), past employment and salary expectation plans for career development. Are the questions similar in Ireland? Thank you.

Comment: Note that Ireland proper (not Northern Ireland) is EU, not UK.

Comment: Which just leads to the question of how different Ireland and Northern Ireland are in academic culture. I'm useless there...

Comment: I'm not in Ireland so can't answer, but Trinity College Dublin careers service has a section on [academic interviews](https://www.tcd.ie/Careers/students/applying/interviews/type.php) which I would assume applies to Irish universities.

Comment: @JonCuster My limited understanding is that the academic culture is similar, but I don't know if the funding environment and political pressures/incentives are different.